# antonym of "recently"

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, context

What are the antonyms of **recently**?

I have checked with a thesaurus and I got just two:

- **before**
- **later**

Neither of those seems to fit into my call to action sentence - `visit 10 URLs that were not accessed for the longest period of time`.

`Visit 10 ... URLs`

```
If I use `before`, sentence does not make sense
If I use `later`, sentence does not seem to make sense either
If I use least visited it does not seem to refer to time but number of visits 
If I use bottom URLs it all depends on the sort order and does not refer to time
```

In contrast, If I would be referring to the recent I can just say:

`Visit 10 most recently accessed URLs.`

What are the antonyms of **recently** that would fit into the context?

Comment: Not an antonym, but you could use *least recently accessed.*

Comment: "to visit 10 URLs that were not visited for the longest period of time" makes no sense. A lot of URLS will **never** have been visited by a specific person (which means there is no "long period of time", since there was no visit in the past). You seem to focus on URLs that **have** been visited, but not recently. So I would describe it as such: "visited URLs that you have not recently visited".

Comment: imagine an unsorted list of 100 URLs where each of the URLs have a timestamp. Now I need a short call to action phrase so, whoever is looking at the list should find and visit  10 URLs that have the oldest timestamp.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says *anciently*. But, *least recently* is fairly idiomatic.

Comment: @jxh It may be idiomatic, but it is also unnecessarily verbose and a bit clunky.

Answer (score 4):

In your case (web site visits), some people use "stalest"

```
visit 10 stalest URLs
```

Comment: I would probably go with *most stale* myself...

Comment: I suppose if it helps make it clearer (or more clear) to a non-native speaker that might be warranted, but stale, staler, stalest are proper. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stale

Comment: I agree it is proper, but "most stale" reads better in my mind, if it is to be used side by side with "most recently".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [anciently](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anciently) is what you’re looking for.